# How to remove/uninstall Advanced REST Client Native Application

Tags: advanced-rest-client

Does anyone knows how to uninstall ARC (Advanced REST Client) Native Application?

I follow the link provided below to install ARC but there is no information for how to uninstall it.

Installation steps are as follow:
1. Click on the link blow (provided)
2. There is an INSTALL link and if you click on it, you will get arc.xxx.deb file downloaded.
3. Open .deb file, via Ubuntu Software Center and install it.

**But, I do not know how to uninstall it. Can someone let me know?**
Thanks in advance.

https://restforchrome.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/moving-data-from-advanced-rest-client.html

Answer (score 2):

Please, check extensions in your Google Chrome browser. If ARC exist - remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get remove advanced-rest-client
```

Hint: when your not sure about the name of a package to remove with apt-get you can search (example, change 'advanced-rest' with what you need):

```
apt-cache search advanced-rest
```